# how to return json from a php function

Tags: php, json

have written a class that uses in built php function DirectoryIterator
which as to show folder structure like this

```
root
   |__subfolder
   |          |_mp3 
   |          |_png
   |__subfolder2
              |_mp3
              |_mp3
```

Here is my class

```
 <?php
  $list = array();

 $dir = new DirectoryIterator('/opt/lampp');
 foreach ($dir as $fileinfo)
 {
 if ($fileinfo->isFile())
  {
    //echo $fileinfo->getBasename() . "\n";
   //echo $fileinfo->getBasename('.jpg') . "\n";
  }
  else
   { //create object with two fields
            $list3 = array( 'name'=> $fileinfo->getFilename(),
                            'type'=> $fileinfo->getType(),
                            'date'=> $fileinfo->getMTime(),
                            'size'=> $fileinfo->getSize());
             array_push($list, $list3);



    }


        $return_array = array('files'=>$list);
        echo json_encode(  $return_array)
     }
     ?>
```

have written the echo json_encode but the string format does not seem to be correctly writen

here is a view of the string format of the out put, am using online json viewer for verification

```
 {"files":[{"name":"info","type":"dir","date":1491647493,"size":4096}]}     {"files":[{"name":"info","type":"dir","date":1491647493,"size":4096},{"name":"pear","type":"dir","date":1491647422,"size":4096}]}{"files":[{"name":"info","type":"dir","date":1491647493,"size":4096},{"name":"pear","type":"dir","date":1491647422,"size":4096},
```

Comment: use json_encode to convert it to json :D

Comment: @JimL, thanks for your response,how  can i archive that, am new to json...?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @MunimMunna thanks for your response, where am i missing some commas..?help me understand

Comment: My mistake, you are not missing comma's, but you are encoding the sub-folders i.e `$list_array`, you need to insert all `$return_array` into `$list` array, then encode the `$list` array outside the `for-loop` at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

use `json_encode()`

```
<?php
  $list = array();

 $dir = new DirectoryIterator('/opt/lampp');
 foreach ($dir as $fileinfo)
 {
 if ($fileinfo->isFile())
  {
    //echo $fileinfo->getBasename() . "\n";
   //echo $fileinfo->getBasename('.jpg') . "\n";
  }
  else
   { //create object with two fields
            $list3 = array( 'name'=> $fileinfo->getFilename(),
                            'type'=> $fileinfo->getType(),
                            'date'=> $fileinfo->getMTime(),
                            'size'=> $fileinfo->getSize());
             array_push($list, $list3);



    }


        $return_array = array('files'=>$list);
        echo json_encode($return_array);

 }


?>
```

Comment: @Hassan thanks for your response , the strings been returned by the json_encode($return_array) is not correctly formatted as a json string

Comment: what format can you show me which format you want

Comment: thansk for your response, the formart i want is this   { "data" : [ { "data":"audio","children" : [ {"data" : {"title":"juicy.mp3"},"attr":{"href": "audio/juicy.mp3","id": "1239"}, "icon": "images\/mp3-icon.gif"},

Comment: now what type format you getting for this  json_encode($return_array)

Comment: {"data":[{"name":"info","type":"dir","date":1491647493,"size":4096}]}{"data":[{"name":"info","type":"dir","date":1491647493,"size":4096},

Comment: its coming proper see your list array keys and values

Comment: when i test it using online json viewer its saying wrong format...? help me understand

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp read this article